# How many ways can n books be placed on k distinguishable shelves if no 2 books are the same and the positions of the books on the shelves matter?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This is the solution provided:
 $$C(k+n-1,n) \times n!$$

I know that $C(k+n-1,n)$ denotes the number of ways n indistinguishable books can be placed on k distinguishable shelves. But I'm not too sure how multiplying that by $n!$ will give us the solution to the question :/

On a side note, when we are given a question that requires us to arrange n distinguishable objects into k distinguishable bins, is it correct to say that to obtain the answer we simply just have to multiply n! to the number of ways required to arrange n indistinguishable objects into k distinguishable bins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $n!$ ways to choose an order for the books. Once chosen this order, we have to place $k-1$ bars between the books to determine where ends a shelf and begins the next one. This is like rearrange a set of $n$ books and $k-1$ bars, and there are $\binom{n+k-1}{n}$ ways to do this.

Comment: Confused about this answer. If there are $n$ books and $k$ shelves, then this is equivalent to having a sequence of $n+k-1$ stars and choosing $k-1$ of these stars to turn into bars. The number of ways to choose $k-1$ stars out of $n+k-1$ stars is ${n+k-1} \choose {k-1}$. The final answer should be $n! \times {{n+k-1} \choose {k-1}}$? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

As an incentive to further study here is an answer using species. The species under consideration is 
$$\mathfrak{S}_{=k}(\mathfrak{S}(\mathcal{Z}))$$ which yields the exponential generating function $$\frac{1}{(1-z)^k}$$ for an answer of
$$n! [z^n] \frac{1}{(1-z)^k}$$
which is
$$n!\times {n+k-1\choose n}.$$